# comparison of channel images in android and matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, android, opencv

so i have a 1024x1024 greyscale image, when i open this picture using matlab, matlab detect that the image is 1024x1024 uint8.

[image: matlab image value detection]

the problem is when I do image processing with android, where I divide the image into several parts, then do the attacking process to some parts of the image, then re-combine the image. then I open the image of the attacking result using matlab, and matlab detect image size 1024x1024x3 uint8. I've tried to change the image using the cvtColor function provided by opencv to change the image channel but the image is still considered 3 channel by matlab. this is a sample image before and after done image processing with android (left:before attacking, right:after attacking)

[image: left:before attacking, right:after attacking]

this is one of the attacking functions named gaussian noised which I implement using android

```
private Bitmap GaussianNoise(Bitmap src, double variance) {
    Bitmap hasil = src;
    Mat input = new Mat();
    Mat imGray = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(src, input);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(input, imGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    Mat noise = new Mat(imGray.size(), CvType.CV_64F);
    Mat resultMat = new Mat();

    Core.normalize(imGray, resultMat, 0.0, 1.0, Core.NORM_MINMAX, CV_64F);
    Core.randn(noise, 0, Math.sqrt(variance));
    Core.add(resultMat, noise, resultMat);
    Core.normalize(resultMat, resultMat, 0.0, 1.0, Core.NORM_MINMAX, CV_64F);
    resultMat.convertTo(resultMat, imGray.type(), 255, 0);
    Utils.matToBitmap(resultMat, hasil);
    return hasil;
}
```

all forms of assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The three layers are R, G and B, where you started with a 1 layer greyscale image... if your image is still greyscale you should be able to just choose any layer  using `im = im(:, :, 1)`.

Comment: so does it matter if matlab detects 3 channel images as long as the value of RGB is same? @Wolfie